# how to get the count of the numbers in an array in a sorted order and then sum it in hive?

Tags: hive

I have the following table

```
select * from teller;
Saeed   ["20","5","5","10","1"]
Joe     ["1","1","5","1","10",]
Henry   ["1","1","1","1","1","5","10"]
Jon     ["1","1","1","1","1","5","10"]
```

The following command gives me to get the count of each of numbers:

```
  Select denomination, count(*) FROM teller LATERAL VIEW explode(bill) subs 
  as denomination GROUP By denomination;
```

my output was

```
1       77
10      73
20      23
5       35
```

I want my output to be in a sorted order of the denomination, I tried:

```
  Select denomination, count(*) FROM teller LATERAL VIEW explode(bill) subs 
  as denomination ORDER By denomination;
```

I get this error:
Expression not in GROUP BY key 'denomination

How do i get it sorted and also how can i sum the numbers?

Comment: which numbers you want to sum? you want to sum per name?

Comment: I think you have missed `GROUP By denomination` before `order by` in your second query

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `group by` before `order by` in your query and it will stop giving you the error.

```
Select denomination, count(*) 
FROM teller LATERAL VIEW explode(bill) subs as denomination 
GROUP BY denomination
ORDER By denomination;
```

If you want a total sum of the above result, you can do:

```
Select SUM(cnt)
FROM 
(Select denomination, count(*) as cnt
FROM teller LATERAL VIEW explode(bill) subs as denomination 
GROUP BY denomination
ORDER By denomination
)a
;
```

Comment: one select is enough: `select count(*) from teller LATERAL VIEW explode(bill) subs as denomination`

Comment: This did not work for me. Even though i do a group by and order by, it still gives me the same answer as the above output.
The sum also gives me the wrong sum.

Comment: Can you paste the expected output?

Comment: i want the output to be
        1       77
        5       35
       10      73
       20      23

        Sum = ((1*77)+ (5*35) +(10*73)+(20*23)) = 1442

Comment: So I got the sorted output, I had my bill datatype as array<string>, I changed that to array<int>
but my sum is still giving me the wrong number.

Comment: I figure the sum:
hive> Select SUM(denomination) FROM teller LATERAL VIEW explode(bill) money as denomination;